# Best approach for loading images from sql database

Tags: android, sql

What is the best approach for loading images from restful api?
Is it by making url reference to them or base64 string?
I have a memory problem with base64, even when I use glide.
So should I make url's and then load them with glide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont store the image into a databse, takes up too much memory instead store the image on the internet or on  a service like amazon s3 bucket and keep the url reference to the image on your database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
So most of other apps on market that are using a lot of images use this approach?

Comment: Yes, if you use amazons S3 service, you can upload images to a bucket which is like a folder which can hold files. You can put files into your bucket or delete files from your bucket pro grammatically using amazons jars through java or whatever other languages amazon provides for their libraries or manually.